# Can I use "To the memory of" for a place in the dedication part of a book?

Tags: dedications

Can I use "To the memory of" for a place in the dedication part of a book? for instance, can I write "to the memory of my childhood gardens, that do not exist anymore"? or is there another expression to use?

Note that my question is different from the question "What's the proper way to dedicate a paper with a “to the memory of”?", which is already answered in this forum. In fact, my question is about the usage of "to the memory of" for a place whereas in that question "to the memory of" is used for a person.

Comment: I don't believe that's a duplicate, because that question (and the phrase "To the memory of", actually) is referring to a deceased **person,** not a thing like gardens.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, exactly what I meant!

Comment: Actually, you can say whatever your publisher allows.

Answer (score 1):

(My personal opinion.)  I would not phrase it the same as if you were dedicating the book to a person.  Instead, you can just plop down one or more meaningful sentences, or even a fragment of a sentence, about the gardens in question.

Or you could dedicate it to your younger self, who enjoyed etc. etc. and work in the gardens here.

One more idea, you could dedicate the book to the gardener(s) who created those gardens.